# Using function instead of procedure to initialize derived type

Tags: initialization, ada, derived

How to to initialize a derived type from `Base` type with a function?

It would look nicer if I could use the `function Create` instead of a procedure.

```
procedure Main is

   type Base is abstract tagged record
      Number : Integer;
   end record;

   type Base1 is new Base with null record;
   type Base2 is new Base with null record;

   --function Create return Base'Class is
   --begin
      --return (Number => 1);
   --end;

   procedure Create ( B : out Base'Class ) is
   begin
      B.Number := 1;
   end;

   B1 : Base1;
   B2 : Base2;

begin

   Create (B1);
   Create (B2);

end Main;
```

Builder result when uncommenting the `function Create`:

```
type of aggreate cannot be class-wide
```

I don't want that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s nothing to stop a function returning an instance of a concrete descendant of an abstract tagged type so long as it knows *which* descendant. Your `Create` doesn’t.

One way would be to supply a parameter saying which concrete class:

```
function Create (Kind : Integer) return Base'Class is
begin
   case Kind is
      when 1 =>
         return Base1'(Number => 1);
      when others =>
         return Base2'(Number => Kind);
   end case;
end Create;
```

Another way would be to declare a function returning `Base`, which would have to be `abstract`, and override for the derived types. This has to be done in a package (I’ve used the Ada2012 feature where you can write a function’s implementation in-line if it’s simple):

```ada
package Types is
   type Base is abstract tagged record
      Number : Integer;
   end record;
   function Create return Base is abstract;

   type Base1 is new Base with null record;
   function Create return Base1 is ((Number => 1));

   type Base2 is new Base with null record;
   function Create return Base2 is ((Number => 2));
end Types;
```

Now, because in Ada a subprogram can dispatch on a function result as well as on a parameter, you can write

```ada
B4 : Types.Base1 := Types.Create;
B5 : Types.Base2 := Types.Create;
```

The trouble with this one is that you’re limited to the parameter profile you specified in the base function.

---

All the above assumes you want the initialization to depend on the actual concrete type. If that’s not so, you can initialize to a constant value with a simple initializer:

```ada
type Base is abstract tagged record
   Number : Integer := 42;
end record;
```

or via a function call:

```ada
type Base is abstract tagged record
   Time : Ada.Calendar.Time := Ada.Calendar.Clock;
end record;
```

Comment: But can I have just one create function? Initialization will be the same for all derived types.

Comment: I take it then that you can’t use something like `Number := 42;` in the record declaration?

Comment: Yes that works for constants but I'm interested for dynamic assignment.

Comment: `Number := {function_call};`, then?

Comment: That works. Never tried that before. I didn't know that was possible.